# Change the bitmap color

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, colormatrix, porter-duff

There is a bitmap with a white background and an orange triangle inside. What I want to do is change the color of the orange triangle to the color I want, how can I do this with code? I used Porterduff and Color Matrix, but did not get the result I wanted.

Original: [click to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4pDq.png)

What I want to do with code: [click to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nDm2.png)

I don't want the white background color to change.

Comment: can you post that bitmap code and also there are various approaches you can follow with this like re-drawing that triangle etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this method to change the color of the bitmap runtime. Give it a try.

```
 public Bitmap replaceColor(Bitmap src,int fromColor, int targetColor) {
        if(src == null) {
            return null;
        }
     // Source image size 
        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        //get pixels
        src.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
 
        for(int x = 0; x < pixels.length; ++x) {
            pixels[x] = (pixels[x] == fromColor) ? targetColor : pixels[x];
        }
     // create result bitmap output 
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
        //set pixels
        result.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
 
        return result;
    }
}
```

Define from and to color in the colors.xml

```
<color name="red">#FB0000</color> 
<color name="yell">#FFC953</color>
```

and use the above method as below.

```
iv.setImageBitmap(replaceColor(bitmap,getResources().getColor(R.color.red),getResources().getColor(R.color.yell)));
```

Comment: how its gonna change the color of that triangular part?

Comment: iv.setImageBitmap(replaceColor(bitmap,getResources().getColor(R.color.red),getResources().getColor(R.color.yell)));

Comment: @HimanshuDudhat Thank you for the code works very well 

Comment: @HimanshuDudhat The code cannot fully recognize colors in large images, is there any code where I can change the entire orange color in a bitmap?